# Unable to use x86 emulator with Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I'm trying to follow along with the [Xamarin guide for Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/). I'm getting an alert saying that x86 emulators are 10x faster. But when I try to use an X86, version whether I create it or using the default one it fails. This happens on windows as well as mac. It works just fine with an arm processor.

Comment: "it fails" is not a very helpful description of the problem

Comment: That's all its giving me. Nothing in the log. Just says "Execution Failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I didn't have HAXM installed. I had to go into the BIOS and enable virtualization. Then install HAXM from Intel's site. For some reason I can do it view SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to use x86 emulator with Xamarin

Have you [disabled `Hyper-V` in your computer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/#Disabling_Hyper-V)? If you didn't turn off this windows feature, you will get error message " it fails" when you  use an X86 Android emulator.

You should [turn off your `Hyper-V`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gmarchetti/2008/12/07/turning-hyper-v-on-and-off/) :

- 1. Run Cmd as administrator
- 2. Execute the following commond :

     ```
     bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
     ```
- 3. Reboot your computer

And if you want a better performance, you should use [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/).

Comment: This didn't help on windows it stay says "There were deployment errors". I will try on my Mac when I get home.

Comment: Please post the complete error log in output window.